# How can I format the algorithm better inside a question?

Tags: support, formatting

I would like to write a pseduocode inside a post with latex, how can I format it. For example in the question: [How to find the interior convex polytope with the maximal volume given a set of 3D points?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/87838/how-to-find-the-interior-convex-polytope-with-the-maximal-volume-given-a-set-of)

How can I have something [like this latex output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163768/write-pseudo-code-in-latex):

[image]

Comment: Why LaTeX? Use Markdown code formatting. You can even have highlighting.

Comment: @Raphael I think the problem is that the code-blocks don't interpret LaTeX. (Although this example doesn't desperately need LaTeX, some pseudo-code blocks definitely do) So the question would be how to get a block which can both (1) interpret LaTeX code and (2) support indentation. That seems like a reasonable question. 
Personally though, I think a good (and precise!) textual description is almost always clearer than a block of pseudo-code. So another option is to simply not write pseudo-code at all.

Comment: @Discretelizard If the pseudocode needs (non-unicode) mathematics, it's _probably_ too mathy.

Comment: Anyway, it's not possible.  You _can_ use LaTeX to typeset algorithms, but with the limitations of MathJax it's a pain in the ass for several reasons.

Comment: @Raphael Yes, but 'unicode replaceable' LaTeX such as greek letters, arrows and summation symbols are used quite often in pseudo-code I've encountered and unicode math is generally a pain in the ass as well. 
Also, what exactly is the problem with 'too mathy' pseudocode?

Comment: @Discretelizard Depends on what questions you're asking, of course. As a rule of thumb, "mathy" pseudocode is rarely useful for detailed analyses. It can be useful for expressing ideas, or formulating high-level/meta algorithms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the formatting using a table for alignment of the labels, manual spacing for indentation and manual typesetting of each word (paying attention to spacing).

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
 & \mathit{stringlen} \leftarrow \text{length of } \mathit{string}. \\
 & \mathit{i} \leftarrow \mathit{patlen}. \\
 \mathit{top}: & \text{if } \mathit{i} \gt \mathit{stringlen} \text{ then return false}. \\
… \\
 & \text{if } \mathit{string}(\mathit{i}) = \mathit{pat}(\mathit{i}) \\
 & \quad \text{then} \\
… \\
\end{array}
$$

But this is painful for many reasons. The source is hard to read and edit. The rendering of such large blocks of MathJax is slow in some browsers. I hate to think what this would sound like on a screen reader. And I don't think your sample output is particularly pretty anyway.

I would use the native text markup. It's perfectly suitable for a nested structure.

- Let $\mathit{stringlen} = \mathrm{length}(\mathit{string})$
- Set $i = \mathit{patlen}$
- While $i \lt \mathit{stringlen}$:

  - Set $j = \mathit{patlen}$
  - While $j \lt 0$:

    - …
- Return false.

This is easier to do with structured code than with goto. But you shouldn't be using goto when loops would do anyway.

[Source code of this post](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/2d5663e0-e341-4364-8c61-1d66668a224a/view-source) ([other revisions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1471/revisions))

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think Markdown code formatting is the way to go:

```
stringlen <- length of string
i <- pathlen
...
i <- i + max( delta_1(string(i)), delta_2(j) )
```

You can use Unicode symbols if you prefer the look:

```
stringlen ← length of string
i ← pathlen
...
i ← i + max( delta₁(string(i)), delta₂(j) )
```

Note that if your pseudo code roughly corresponds to a real programming language, you may be able to use [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/156248) to good effect.