# MathJax on Meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax, meta

I can't believe this has never been requested! Please activate MathJax on Computer Science Meta. It's necessary to provide support about MathJax usage.

Meta sites should automatically have the same markup extensions as the main site.

Comment: Hmm, I notice math.meta has mathjax. So, yes, why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're not really sure why it wasn't turned on for Meta - it should have been enabled here when it was enabled on main. It's enabled now. :)

Comment: Thanks. Is there caching involved? https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1470/how-can-i-format-the-algorithm-better-inside-a-question/1471#1471 shows MathJax rendering, but it's [partially broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHF1w.png): in the first math block, line breaks are missing, but they appear correctly [in the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sILW1.png).

Comment: @Gilles Apparently the ``\``s at the end of the line have to be escaped when printed onto the page, which is something that is only done by the server at render time when MathJax is formally enabled.